# When Template Engine Can be used via Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, pug, template-engine

I decide to use  template engine (Like JADE/PUG) for using via Angluar 2.0 for clarity and cleaning the code for developing a big single page application (SPA) and just I want to reach a very good performance application.

> My Combination is : HTML5+CSS (SASS)+ ANGULAR 2 + Bootstrap

My question is that, is it reasonable to use template engine for clarity and cleaning the code for developing a big single page application (SPA) along with Angular 2.0? I read about [JADE](https://www.slant.co/topics/51/viewpoints/7/~javascript-templating-engines~pug-jade#title) but now in a doubt.

Answer (score 1):

... What i suggest to you (based on my current stack) is to use HTML but in External files ...and link it to your component via require ... so webpack can do the magic rest for you.

for example:

```
 import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    import "fullcalendar";


    require('style!fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css');


    @Component({
        selector: 'about',
        template: require('./about.component.html'),
        styles: [String(require('./about.component.scss'))]
    })

    export default class AboutComponent implements AfterViewInit {
        calendarElement: any;
        public message: string;

        constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

        ngAfterViewInit() {
            this.calendarElement = jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
            this.calendarElement.fullCalendar({});
        }

    }
```

As you can see I'm also using same thing for include external sass files in my component

Comment: So you means no template engine will be required?

Comment: Yes sure... and i think it's better.. using somtehing like Jade is ok if you have to do very simple stuff .. but it's my opinion... but now if you are searching for something similar (server side rendering of you html + css+ js) ...try to take a look at Angular Universal (it's very good also for SEO) https://universal.angular.io/

Comment: So as a a result we can conclude that  HTML5+CSS (SASS)+ ANGULAR 2 + Bootstrap is very good and no template engine will be requried to get the best performance. (Fast App).

Comment: For me yes ... One thig  you can do to improve performance is to put you template(HTML) in angular Cache in string .. but it was for Angular 1 with a  gulp module but in Angular 2 with webpack  it's out of the box

Comment: Wow :) very thanks. so If I understand correctly we should find an alternate to web-pack :) you are so expert

Comment: if you use Angular 2 with Webpack and you include external html like i showed to you (with require(''html-file.html)) you don't do nothing... it do the magic for you .. but only in ANGULAR 2 and Webpack .. in Angular 1 you have to do it by yourself

Answer (score -1):

JADE is not suitable for a SPA.

JADE is a server side view technology, which renders HTML with the required data, that is suitable for a traditional non-SPA application.

In SPA, you just get only data (not HTML every time) from the server.

Comment: Why? Would you please let me know, what is good, why?

Comment: you are right. in SPA we get data and whole page doesn't need to refresh. so what is the best one here?

Comment: All your other selections like HTML5, CSS, Bootstrap are good, simply get rid of JADE (and any other server side view libraries) and get your data from the server using an Angular 2 service.

Comment: what is the main reason to use template engine?